# Как правильно вытянуть Лайки из youtube?

Tags: java, youtube-api

Хочу добавить в приложение возможность вытягивать лайки и дизлайки из указанных видео. Вернее я это реализовал парсингом страницы, но данное решение мне кажется ресурсоемким.
Захотел научиться пользоваться Youtube-api и в связи с этим возникло несколько вопросов:

1. Насколько я понял из документации то для таких запросов авторизация и ключ необязательны, так как я не добавляю и не изменяю контент. Верно ли это?
2. Как подсказывает api-explorer я могу сформировать запрос типа

   ```
     POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?id=G2X3DVVJL2Q&rating=like&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
   ```

Возможна ли передача всей ссылки в определенный метод api. Что должен вернуть запрос? String, int, json?

Приведенные в документации примеры сложней моей задачи, но при этом не открывают ее решения.

Answer (score -1):

Почитайте документацию по их апи на офф сайте разработчика - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests , там описаны все запросы для получения информации

Comment: Мне нужна реализация запроса на java. Тело запроса я генерировать смогу. В примерах java я не нашел способа это сделать без авторизации и цельным запросом.

Comment: @VictorMorozov Ну так возьмите отправьте запрос, считайте полученный JSON объект

Comment: Вопрос: как отправить запрос    Ответ: возьмите и отправьте :)

Comment: По вашему будет достаточно запросов вида                                 URLConnection connection = new URL(" ").openConnection();             Если да то ответьте, это ваше мнение или факт? Работали ли вы с Youtube data api или это теория?

Comment: @VictorMorozov Я работал и с yotube api и с Vk api. Что там, что там принцип один и тот же. Вы бы, я не знаю, в браузер вбили бы uri, да посмотрели на результат